# SQL Group by Month

Tags: group-by

I have a table of Sales data with each line as a sale date mm/dd/yy.

I'm trying to create a query so I can see total sales for each month I have. 
Would I have to create a column separate that dictates only the month? Or is there a way that it can take the month from that date format?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: You don't need a separate column. You can group by the result of a function call.

The details of what that function might depend on your database, how you want results formatted, and performance considerations.

The following both work in Oracle:

```
SELECT extract(YEAR FROM ae.saledate), extract(MONTH FROM ae.saledate), count(*)
FROM mytable ae
GROUP BY extract(YEAR FROM ae.saledate), extract(MONTH FROM ae.saledate);

SELECT TO_CHAR(ae.saledate, 'YYYY-MM'), count(*)
FROM mytable ae
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ae.saledate, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Edited to add versions that ignore year and only look at month (since I was making an assumption above that wasn't actually in the question):

```
SELECT extract(MONTH FROM ae.saledate), count(*)
FROM mytable ae
GROUP BY extract(MONTH FROM ae.saledate);

SELECT TO_CHAR(ae.saledate, 'MM'), count(*)
FROM mytable ae
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ae.saledate, 'MM');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Query will helpful.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(SalesDate DATETime,
Amount float
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT '2016-01-12', 12
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-13', 12
UNION
SELECT '2016-02-12', 12
UNION
SELECT '2016-03-12', 12

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), SalesDate, 120) AS 'YYYY-MM', 
SUM(Amount) as 'Amount'
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), SalesDate, 120)
```

OUTPUT :

```
YYYY-MM Amount
------- ----------------------
2016-01  24
2016-02  12
2016-03  12

(3 row(s) affected)
```

For only Month Wise

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), SalesDate, 120), 2) AS 'MM', 
sum(Amount) as 'Amount'
from #Temp
group by RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), SalesDate, 120), 2)
```

Output:

```
MM   Amount
---- ----------------------
01   24
02   12
03   12

(3 row(s) affected)
```